# need to query MongoDB using php

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I need to query mongodb with something like this:

`("something" < X OR "something" = "nll") 
       AND 
    ("someother">X OR "someother"= "nll") AND z=$z AND s=1`

I've tried a few things, but can't get it to work, this is what I've tried:

`find( 
      array(
       '$or'=>array(array("something"=>array("$le",$X)),array("something"=>"nll")),
       '$or'=>array(array("someother"=>array("$ge",$X)),array("someother"=>"nll"))
      ))`

But that's getting me the OR overwritten, so I'm lost on that...

After diggin a bit more, I assembled this code that seems to be what I need, but doesn't work either:

`find( array('$and'=>array( array( '$or' => array( array("something"=>array('$gte'=>$X)),array("something"=>"nll"))), array('$or' => array( array("someother"=>array('$lte'=>$X)),array("someother"=>"nll")))),"Z"=>$z, "s"=>"1");`

But this doesn't work as it returns zero results and I know for sure that there are more than 2 items that match on the db. (100% certain)

Answer (score 0):

```
$range = array('$and' => array(  
     array('$or' => array(
         array("something" => array( "$lte" => $X)),
         array("something" => "null")),
     array('$or' => array(
          array("someother" => array("$gte" => $X)),
          array("someother" => "null"))   
));
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work for me like that... it didn't return any result and I'm sure there are more than 1...

Comment: something $exists or is only string "null" ?

Comment: "something" exists, but it can have null value, and I need the results that match any of the cases (null or the selected value) and they also match any of the "someother" cases (null or selected value)

Comment: By the way, the null is not C null, it's the string "null", for practical approach, we can consider the string as "NLL" so it's not leading to any confusion.

Comment: I update my query, but not syntax checked. Other think why add 'null'. Leave it and when query just check if exists $exists http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists